# carrinho autonomo com dois eixos erro de compilação

Tags: c++

ola.. sou iniciante e estou desenvolvendo um carrinho altonomo e encontrei um erro na compilação

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Linux), Placa:"Arduino Uno"

/home/acer/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/carrinho_autonomo1.0/carrinho_autonomo1.0.ino: In function 'void loop()':
carrinho_autonomo1.0:54:9: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
else (distacia < 500){
^~~~
carrinho_autonomo1.0:54:15: error: 'distacia' was not declared in this scope
else (distacia < 500){
^~~~~~~~
/home/acer/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/carrinho_autonomo1.0/carrinho_autonomo1.0.ino:54:15: note: suggested alternative: 'distancia'
else (distacia < 500){
^~~~~~~~
distancia
carrinho_autonomo1.0:66:9: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
else (acao != "esquerda"){
^~~~
carrinho_autonomo1.0:66:34: error: expected ';' before '{' token
else (acao != "esquerda"){
^
carrinho_autonomo1.0:73:11: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
else (acao == "esquerda"){
^~~~
carrinho_autonomo1.0:73:36: error: expected ';' before '{' token
else (acao == "esquerda"){
^
carrinho_autonomo1.0:79:11: error: break statement not within loop or switch
break
^~~~~
carrinho_autonomo1.0:80:5: error: expected ';' before '}' token
}
^
exit status 1
'else' without a previous 'if'

esse é o erro.

segue o codigo
/*segundo programa18/11*/

#include<Ultrasonic.h>

//define os pinos do ultrasonico

#define triger    12
#define echo      13

// define os pinos contrladores do motor traseiro
#define pmt1      3
#define pmt2      5

//define pinos direçao veiculo

#define pdir    0
#define pesq    1

//inicializa sensor ultrasonicos
Ultrasonic ultrasonic(triger, echo);

int velocidade =0;
String acao;

void setup() {
// inicia monitor serial
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode (pmt1, OUTPUT);
pinMode (pmt2, OUTPUT);
pinMode (pdir, OUTPUT);
pinMode (pesq, OUTPUT);
//char acao;
}

void loop() {
//faz leitura da distancia
int distancia;

distancia = ultrasonic.read();
Serial.print ("distancia em cm:");
Serial.println (distancia);
delay(1000);

//determina velocidade
//int velocidade;
if (distancia>1000){
//      velociade = 192;
Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 75% do rpm");
}
else (distancia < 1000 and distancia > 500);{
velocidade = 128;
Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 50% do rpm");
}
else (distacia < 500){
velocidade = 64;
Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 25% do rpm");
}

//analise de acao (frente, direita, esquerda, ou re

//char acao;
String acao;

```
if (distancia<200);{
    //vira pra direita        
    else (acao != "esquerda"){
      digitalWrite(pdir,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(pesq,LOW);
      acao="esquerda";
      //FALTA SUB PARA TRACIONAR MOTOR
      }
      //vira pra esquerda
      else (acao == "esquerda"){
        digitalWrite(pdir,LOW);
        digitalWrite(pesq,HIGH);
        acao="direita";
        //falta sub para tracionar motor
      }
      break
}
```

}

obrigado

Comment: Esse seu primeiro else deveria ser um if.

Answer (score 0):

A correção dos erros relacionados as estruturas condicionais **if** e **else** são relativamentes simples, basta garantir que quando um **else** for inserido no código, esse deve ser precedido de um **if**. 
Por Exemplo, o código abaixo irá resultar em um erro de compilação pois, você está inserindo um **else** sem possuir seu **if**.

```
// Esse código gera um erro de compilação
if (distancia < 200)
{ 
    // Esse "else" não possui um if antes
    else (acao != "esquerda")
    {
        // Faça algo
    }
    else (acao == "esquerda")
    {
        // Faça algo
    }
}
```

Nesse caso a solução é relativamente simples basta subistituir o primeiro **else** por um **if** que, seria o comportamento desejado, após isso deve-se verificar também que você está realizando outra verificação, portanto, é necessário inserir outro **if** antes da condição, tornando o código assim.

```
// Esse código compila
if (distancia < 200)
{ 
    if (acao != "esquerda")
    {
        // Faça algo
    }
    else if (acao == "esquerda")
    {
        // Faça algo
    }
}
```

Logo, basta aplicar esses princípios em todo o resto do seu código e deste modo os erros relacionados as estruturas condicionais serão solucionados.

---

Vale observar também que se você estiver utilizando a biblioteca **Ultrasonic.h** do filipeflop, esta não possui um método **read()**, como você coloca nesta linha `distancia = ultrasonic.read();`.
Portanto, seguindo conforme o exemplo no site do [filipeflop](https://www.filipeflop.com/blog/sensor-ultrassonico-hc-sr04-ao-arduino/):

Basta copiar o trecho de código que é usado para calcular a distância em centímetros e após isso atribuir à variável **distancia**, resultando em algo assim.

```
// Realiza a leitura da distância fornecida pelo sensor
float cmMsec;
long microsec = ultrasonic.timing();
cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);

// Atribui a distância lida à variável "distancia" utilizando o cast.
int distancia = (int)cmMsec;
```

Por fim, o código seu deve resultar em algo similar a isto:

```
#include<Ultrasonic.h>

// Definição dos pinos do sensor ultrassônico
#define triger 12
#define echo 13

// Definição dos pinos para controle do motor traseiro
#define pdir 0 
#define pesq 1

// Definição dos pinos para controle da direção do veículo
#define pmt1 3
#define pmt2 5

int velocidade = 0;
String acao = "";

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(triger, echo);

void setup()
{
    // Inicialização do monitor serial
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Configuração dos pinos
    pinMode(pmt1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pmt2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pdir, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pesq, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // Realiza a leitura da distância fornecida pelo sensor
    float cmMsec;
    long microsec = ultrasonic.timing();
    cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);

    // Atribui a distância lida à variável "distancia" utilizando o cast.
    int distancia = (int)cmMsec;

    // Imprime a distância lida pelo sensor
    Serial.print("distancia em cm:");
    Serial.println(distancia);

    delay(1000);

    // Inicia as verificações
    if (distancia > 1000)
    {
        velocidade = 192;
        Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 75% do rpm");
    }
    else if (distancia < 1000 && distancia > 500)
    {
        velocidade = 128;
        Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 50% do rpm");
    }
    else if (distancia < 500)
    {
        velocidade = 64;
        Serial.println("velocidade selecionada 25% do rpm");
    }

    if (distancia < 200)
    {
        if (acao != "esquerda")
        {
            digitalWrite(pdir, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(pesq, LOW);

            acao = "esquerda";
        }
        else if (acao == "esquerda")
        {
            digitalWrite(pdir, LOW);
            digitalWrite(pesq, HIGH);

            acao = "direita";
        }
    }
}
```